# What does the second parameter in ReactDOM.render mean?

Tags: reactjs

I've just started learning React and in the ReactDOM.render there is `document.getElementById('someid')`, what does it do?

Comment: It's specifying a container for your react app to render inside, generally it's worth looking at the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render) or official sources for what specific parameters mean.

Comment: for example if you have App component, it's injecting App in the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the container to which the contents of the first parameter will be rendered to.

Check out `public/index.html` in your project if you use create-react-app. You should be able to find the `<div>` with an ID of `root` (the default value for create-react-app). You can change the ID of that div, but you will have to change the ID in the getElementById call in your index.js.

Here's what the documentation says about it: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render

> `ReactDOM.render(element, container[, callback])`
>
> Render a React element into the DOM in the supplied container and
>   return a reference to the component (or returns null for stateless
>   components).
>
> If the React element was previously rendered into container, this will
>   perform an update on it and only mutate the DOM as necessary to
>   reflect the latest React element.